# Method in infix notation without defined object

Tags: scala, infix-notation

I have the following Scala Object:

```
object myCls {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    print getString()
  }

  def getString(): String = {
    return "myString"
  }
}
```

On the line:

```
print getString()
```

I get the issue:

```
Cannot resolve symbol getString
```

What's wrong with this method?

Comment: do print(getString())

Comment: Ok. Now it compiles. Why wasn't `print getString()` working?

Comment: because it is not a valid syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [*Infix Expression*](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations) in the specification you see:

```
InfixExpr    ::=  PrefixExpr
               |  InfixExpr id [nl] InfixExpr
PrefixExpr   ::=  [`-' | `+' | `~' | `!'] SimpleExpr
SimpleExpr   ::=  `new' (ClassTemplate | TemplateBody)
               |  BlockExpr
               |  SimpleExpr1 [`_']
```

When the Scala compiler looks at the syntax for [*infix notation*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html), it is of the form:

```
PrefixExpr
| InfixExpr id [nl] InfixExpr`
```

We can think of as `object -> method -> parameters (0 or 1)`

In the example you posted, because `print` is a method defined in `Predef`, which is implicitly imported, we don't have the `PrefixExpr` preceding the `[Identifier[NewLine]]`.

In order for this to work, we need to *explicitly* invoke `print` via `Predef`:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def getString(): String = {
    "myString"
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

getString: ()String

scala> print getString()
<console>:11: error: missing arguments for method print in object Predef;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       print getString()
       ^

scala> Predef print getString()
myString
scala>
```

Since `getString` is of arity-0, we can also drop the parenthesis around it:

```
scala> Predef print getString
myString
```